# find and Replace value inside the list inside data frame

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe, replace

I have a dataframe and the value inside the column are in the list . I need to replace few value form the list .

I want replace "," with ";" and i dont want the brackets "[]" i want them in a string

sample Data in dataframe:

```
[Yuengert Andrew M.]
[Chen Tianxu, Tribbitt Mark A., Yang Yi, Li Xi]
[Wright Chadwick L., Niederkohr Ryan D., Knopp]
```

expected out put :

```
Yuengert Andrew M.
Chen Tianxu; Tribbitt Mark A.; Yang Yi; Li Xi
Wright Chadwick L.; Niederkohr Ryan D.; Knopp
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `join` if values are `lists`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':[['Yuengert Andrew M.'], 
                          ['Chen Tianxu', 'Tribbitt Mark A.', 'Yang Yi', 'Li Xi'],
                          ['Wright Chadwick L.', 'Niederkohr Ryan D.', 'Knopp']]})
print (df)
                                               col
0                             [Yuengert Andrew M.]
1  [Chen Tianxu, Tribbitt Mark A., Yang Yi, Li Xi]
2  [Wright Chadwick L., Niederkohr Ryan D., Knopp]


print (type(df.loc[0, 'col']))
<class 'list'>

df['col'] = df['col'].apply('; '.join)
print (df)
                                             col
0                             Yuengert Andrew M.
1  Chen Tianxu; Tribbitt Mark A.; Yang Yi; Li Xi
2  Wright Chadwick L.; Niederkohr Ryan D.; Knopp
```

Another solution:

```
df['col'] = ['; '.join(x) for x in df['col']]
print (df)
                                             col
0                             Yuengert Andrew M.
1  Chen Tianxu; Tribbitt Mark A.; Yang Yi; Li Xi
2  Wright Chadwick L.; Niederkohr Ryan D.; Knopp
```

---

But if `strings` [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) `^` match start of string and `$` end of string:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ['[Yuengert Andrew M.]', 
                           '[Chen Tianxu, Tribbitt Mark A., Yang Yi, Li Xi]',
                           '[Wright Chadwick L., Niederkohr Ryan D., Knopp]']})
print (df)
                                               col
0                             [Yuengert Andrew M.]
1  [Chen Tianxu, Tribbitt Mark A., Yang Yi, Li Xi]
2  [Wright Chadwick L., Niederkohr Ryan D., Knopp]

print (type(df.loc[0, 'col']))
<class 'str'>

df['col']  = df['col'].replace(['^\[|\]$', ','],['', ';'],regex=True)
print (df)
                                             col
0                             Yuengert Andrew M.
1  Chen Tianxu; Tribbitt Mark A.; Yang Yi; Li Xi
2  Wright Chadwick L.; Niederkohr Ryan D.; Knopp
```

Another solution with [`str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) and [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df['col']  = df['col'].str.strip('[]').str.replace(',', ';')
print (df)
                                             col
0                             Yuengert Andrew M.
1  Chen Tianxu; Tribbitt Mark A.; Yang Yi; Li Xi
2  Wright Chadwick L.; Niederkohr Ryan D.; Knopp
```

Answer (score 1):

If values are in fact lists then use [**`pandas.Series.str.join`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.join.html)

```
df.col.str.join('; ')

0                               Yuengert Andrew M.
1    Chen Tianxu; Tribbitt Mark A.; Yang Yi; Li Xi
2    Wright Chadwick L.; Niederkohr Ryan D.; Knopp
Name: col, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

If your column is in raw string format instead of list, you can do:

```
df.col.replace('\[|\]','',regex=True).str.split(',').str.join(';')
Out[48]: 
0                               Yuengert Andrew M.
1    Chen Tianxu; Tribbitt Mark A.; Yang Yi; Li Xi
2    Wright Chadwick L.; Niederkohr Ryan D.; Knopp
Name: col, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have data as below, you can process it using simple join.

```
col = {'col':[['Yuengert Andrew M.'], 
                          ['Chen Tianxu', 'Tribbitt Mark A.', 'Yang Yi', 'Li Xi'],
                          ['Wright Chadwick L.', 'Niederkohr Ryan D.', 'Knopp']]}
y = ' '.join(['; '.join(i) for i in col['col']])
print (y)
```

output will be:

```
'Yuengert Andrew M. Chen Tianxu; Tribbitt Mark A.; Yang Yi; Li Xi Wright Chadwick L.; Niederkohr Ryan D.; Knopp'
```